# Python - How to decrease big O and increase efficiency in multiple nested for loops?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested, big-o

I wrote a python script that calculates all possibilities where the following conditions are met:

1. a^(2) + b^(2) + c^(2) + d^(2) + e^(2) = f^(2)
2. a,b,c,d,e,f are distinct and nonzero integers
3. a,b,c,d,e are even numbers between twin primes (e.g. 11 & 13 are twin primes, so 12 is a valid possibility)
4. f ≤ 65535
5. the sum of the digits of a == the sum of the digits of b == the sum of the digits of c == the sum of the digits of d == the sum of the digits of e == the sum of the digits of f

I'm not positive whether there will be any results when including criteria 5, but I'd like to find out in a timely manner at least. Ideally, the following conditions should also be met:

6. results that use the same values for a,b,c,d,e,f but in a different order should not be in the results; ideally they should be excluded from the for loops as well
7. results should be sorted by lowest value of a first, lowest value of b first and so and so forth

My question would be, how can I decrease the operating time and increase efficiency?

```
import itertools
import time

start_time = time.time()

def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def generate_twin_primes(start, end):
    for i in range(start, end):
        j = i + 2
        if(is_prime(i) and is_prime(j)):
            n = text_file2.write(str(i+1) + '\n')

def sum_digits(n):
   r = 0
   while n:
       r, n = r + n % 10, n // 10
   return r

def is_sorted(vals):
    for i in range(len(vals)-2):
        if vals[i] < vals[i+1]:
            return False
    return True

def pythagorean_sixlet():
    valid = []
    for a in x:
        for b in x:
            for c in x:
                for d in x:
                    for e in x:
                        f = (a * a + b * b + c * c + d * d + e * e)**(1/2)
                        if f % 1 == 0 and all(x[0]!=x[1] for x in list(itertools.combinations([a, b, c, d, e], 2))):
                            if sum_digits(a) == sum_digits(b) == sum_digits(c) == sum_digits(d) == sum_digits(e) == sum_digits(int(f)):
                                valid.append([a, b, c, d, e, int(f)])
    for valid_entry in valid:
        if is_sorted(valid_entry):
            with open("output.txt", "a") as text_file1:
                text_file1.write(str(valid_entry[0]) + " " + str(valid_entry[1]) + " " + str(valid_entry[2]) + " " + str(valid_entry[3]) + " " + str(valid_entry[4]) + " | " + str(valid_entry[5]) + '\n')
                text_file1.close()

#input #currently all even numbers between twin primes under 1000
text_file2 = open("input.txt", "w")
generate_twin_primes(2, 1000)
text_file2.close()

# counting number of lines in "input.txt" and calculating number of potential possibilities to go through
count = 0
fname = "input.txt"
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        count += 1
print("Number of lines:", count)
print("Number of potential possibilites:", count**5)

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    x = f.read().splitlines()
    x = [int(px) for px in x]

pythagorean_sixlet()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this smells a lot like a HW problem, so we can't give away the farm too easy...  :)

A couple things to consider:

1. if you want to check unique combinations, the number of possibilities is reduced a good chunk from `count**5`, right?
2. You are doing all of your checking at the inner-most part of the loop.  Can you do some checking along the way so that you don't have to generate and test **all** of the possibilities, which is "expensive."
3. If you do choose to keep your check for uniqueness in the inner portion, find a better way that making all the combinations...that is wayyyyy expensive.  Hint:  If you made a set of the numbers you have, what would it tell you?

Implementing some of the above:

```
Number of candidate twin primes between [2, 64152]: 846

total candidate solutions: 1795713740 [need to check f for these]
elapsed:  5.957056045532227

size of result set: 27546
20 random selections from the group:
(40086.0, [3852, 4482, 13680, 20808, 30852])
(45774.0, [6552, 10458, 17028, 23832, 32940])
(56430.0, [1278, 13932, 16452, 27108, 44532])
(64746.0, [15732, 17208, 20772, 32562, 46440])
(47610.0, [3852, 9432, 22158, 24372, 32832])
(53046.0, [3852, 17208, 20772, 23058, 39240])
(36054.0, [4518, 4932, 16452, 21492, 22860])
(18396.0, [3258, 4518, 5742, 9342, 13680])
(45000.0, [2970, 10890, 16650, 18540, 35730])
(59976.0, [2970, 9342, 20772, 35802, 42282])
(42246.0, [3528, 5652, 17208, 25308, 28350])
(39870.0, [3528, 7308, 16362, 23292, 26712])
(64656.0, [8820, 13932, 16452, 36108, 48312])
(61200.0, [198, 882, 22158, 35532, 44622])
(55350.0, [3168, 3672, 5652, 15732, 52542])
(14526.0, [1278, 3528, 7128, 7560, 9432])
(65106.0, [5652, 30852, 31248, 32832, 34650])
(63612.0, [2088, 16830, 26730, 33750, 43650])
(42066.0, [2088, 13932, 15642, 23832, 27540])
(31950.0, [828, 3582, 13932, 16452, 23292])
--- 2872.701852083206 seconds ---
[Finished in 2872.9s]
```

Comment: 1. Do you mean that it should be at the very least count * count-1 * count-2 * count-3 * count-4? 
2/3 Not sure what to make of this, sorry :(

Comment: @Batnovice.  yes.  That will save you a bit of overhead.  Focus on 2 above.  Very few of your selections will pass the sum of digits test.  What can you do besides exploring that all the way at the bottom of your 6th loop?  Can you cut off bad explorations early?  (hint: yes)

Comment: Alright, yes, that makes sense. When including the sum criteria it makes much more sense to do this as early as possible and not in the inner loop. Still, it's not good enough to do it fast enough in Python. It proved much harder to do in C++, but also a LOT quicker. I guess the question isn't really answered as of yet, but I went with C++ to do it instead.

Comment: @Batnovice, well language doesn't matter as much as algorithm.  By making combinations of numbers that pass rule #5 in advance, which is very stringent, I have it running in python in less that 0.1 seconds on an old iMac.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the only reason it runs so fast for you is because the number of primes isn't out currently maxed out. Change "generate_twin_primes(2, 1000)" to  "generate_twin_primes(2, 64153)" (64152 is the highest value for 'a' while still having 'f ≤ 65535') and you're welcome to give me the output in a couple of weeks :) Still over 10K results while meeting criteria 1 through 5.

Comment: @Batnovice OK champ.  Without imposing a limit on f (criteria 4 above...it wasn't in your codebase), I have 59,887 valid combinations using an upper limit on "twin primes" of 64153.  Run time:  3051 seconds (50 minutes << weeks).  Probably left a few minor optimizations on the floor, which would speed that up a bit.  I will impose the upper limit on f and re-run, which will be even a bit faster.

Comment: Ok, that's impressive and I've highly over-estimated the time needed lol. You're right I had forgotten to make sure that results where f > 65535 were ignored. There's something wrong with your random set of results, though. Check the second result, for instance, sum of the digits of 'f' is 27, sum for the others is 18. 
My c++ code yields almost 14K results, in about 10 seconds! This is multithreaded (for 8 threads), though ;) Could you check if you also get that ~14K results with the proper check on sum of the digits of 'f'? If not, my c++ implementation might be at fault.

Comment: yeah, compiled languages have some advantages with tight-loop math operations.  Python might be able to catch up with some vectorizing of this, but that needs thought/work.  Yes, I did mistakenly dump the check on sum of f's digits.  After putting that back in and a little tuning, I get 13,795 results in 2250 seconds.

Comment: Awesome, that's the same number of results I've got. I'm still amazed at the difference in time, although coding in c++, making it multithreaded and using recent hardware probably explains this. Anyway, thanks for your effort and time.